# Сортировка данных из нескольких текстовых документов в один

Tags: sql

Есть несколько текстовых файлов с данными из БД, например first_name, last_name, email, age, password и т.д.(в каждом документе данные записаны в разном порядке и в некоторых не один аккаунт) Нужно чтобы данные из этих документов записывались в один документ по принципу *название документа - email - пароль*, в столбик. Есть ли какая-то программа, которая может это осуществить? Если нет, то что вы могли бы посоветовать? Спасибо.

Comment: Удалить этот хлам и выгрузить в нужном формате. В крайнем случае - загрузить их все в БД (а хоть бы и MS Access, да даже Excel сойдёт, если файлов немного), и там "причесать".

Comment: Такая программка или скрипт пишется почти на любом языке программирования за очень короткое время (не больше часа). Вы начните, мы поможем.

Comment: python подойдет?)